# How to give autoincrement column as alpha numeric values in mysql

Tags: mysql, node.js

I created one table with id,EMP_ID,name. and here id is autoincrement and EMP_ID is unique .I want EMP_ID as E_(id values)). 
for example I want to insert the value as

```
1,E_1,name1
2,E_2,name2
3,E_3,name3
```

how is it possible . I saw trigger codes . but i want to know anyother method in insert query .

Comment: Just use a view with `CONCAT('E_', id) AS EMP_ID`

Comment: You could use the function @Nick mentioned. Also you could try to use `LAST_INSERT_ID()` function to get the ID you need.

Comment: Ask yourself if you really need that. You will make it much harder to work with the ID afterwards. Simple things like select * from table_emp where ID > X won't work anymore.

Comment: I can't imagine a real world case for this situation